# Using sudo with for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, sudo

I want to run a simple for loop command with sudo, but it isn't working:

```
sudo -i -u user for i in /dir; do echo $i; done
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Probably a very simple thing I am overlooking.  Any help?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

sudo wants a program (+arguments) as a parameter, not a piece of shell script. You can do this, though:

```
sudo -i -u user sh -c 'for i in /dir; do echo $i; done'
```

Note the single quotes. If you used double quotes, your shell would try to expand the `$i` before sudo (or, rather, the shell run by it) ever sees it.

PS. a separate problem, as pointed out in a comment (only six years later), is that if you want to iterate over the files in a directory, the proper syntax is `for i in /dir/*`. `for` accepts a list, and `/dir` is a list... with one item. `/dir/*` expands to a list of files in `/dir` due to wildcard expansion.

Comment: you got it! Good luck to all.

Comment: According to this, every output file will be written/saved in the home directory of the specified user. What if I want the output to be written in a specific one?

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin the example doesn't write any output files. Seems like your comment is about an unspecified variation on the question...?

Comment: using back-quotes
sudo -i -u root sh -c 'for i in /dir; do echo $i; done' 
gives me:   sh: /dir: Is a directory  
Using single quotes returns nothing ...
(Redhat)

Comment: @user1767316 I can't believe nobody noticed this before. I've added a note to the post. Thanks for your comment pointing this out!

Comment: Using this: `sudo -i -u user sh -c 'for i in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/autosuspend; do echo -1 > $i; done'` I get a syntax error saying `Syntax error: ";" unexpected`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Max this works fine for me; tested with dash, bash and zsh. I think either something is messing up your command (if you haven't been typing it directly into a shell), or your `/bin/sh` is an alias for some other shell...

Comment: I had to remove the `-i` flag to run a python script as an other user, otherwise it was not able to find the `script.py` file in the loop.

Comment: @JanKrüger Thanks for checking this again for me. Anyway, my shell is definitely a bash shell. I checked with `ps -p $$`. I decided to put the commands in a bash-script now and then execute the script as `sudo`

Comment: Unfortunately, it works, but not as expected/desired
Namely,
[someuser ~]$ sudo -s /bin/sh  -c -E 'for i in a b c* ; do echo $i; done'



[someuser ~]$

instead of 

[someuser ~]$ for i in a b c ; do echo $i; done
a
b
c
[someuser ~]$

Answer (score 7):

You can try sudo bash -c 'commands here'

Answer (score 2):

Put the sudo inside the loop:

```
for i in /dir; do
    sudo -u user somecommand $i
done
```

This won't work without extra steps if you need the other user's permissions to generate the glob for the loop, for example.

Comment: The problem with this is that if the sudo timeout is not big enough, it will ask for the password all the time :(

Comment: I think this answer is not complete, and if you want to access/read files at "dir", you need sudo beforehand, so vote down...sorry!